# Hovering is not working for overlapped div in Html page

Tags: html, css

I am developing web interface for display videos. I have created a table with 4 column. Then I have added header & footer bars. Header bar is for display video name and footer bar is for add play, pause and full screen buttons. When I hover on relevant td those bars should be display accordingly. Now I developed for only one td and header is working as expected but footer is not. Below I have mentioned my code.

```css
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
}

.videocontent{
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #78b5e9;
}

.videocontent .header {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #cccccc;
    background: #1f1f1f;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none; 
}

.videocontent .header .text {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px !important;
}

.videocontent .footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -50px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    color: #ccc;
    background: #1f1f1f;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none; 
}

.videocontent:HOVER .header{
    top: 0px;
    display: block; 
}

.videocontent:HOVER .footer{
    bottom: 0px;
    display: block; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <div>
        <table class="wrapper">
            <tr>
                <td class="videocontent">
                <div id="content1" ></div>
                <div class="header" >[text]</div>
                <div class="footer" ></div>
                </td>

                <td class="videocontent"><div id="content2" ></div></td>
            </tr>
                                        
            <tr>
                <td class="videocontent"><div id="content3" ></div></td>
                <td class="videocontent"><div id="content4" ></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify position of `videocontent` as relative then it will work else your footer will be at the bottom of last `tr` and header will be at `top` of first row. Irrespective of which `td` you are hovering.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
}

.videocontent {
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #78b5e9;
  position: relative;
}

.videocontent .header {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #cccccc;
  background: #1f1f1f;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.videocontent .header .text {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px !important;
}

.videocontent .footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  color: #ccc;
  background: #1f1f1f;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.videocontent:HOVER .header {
  top: 0px;
  display: block;
}

.videocontent:HOVER .footer {
  bottom: 0px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div>
    <table class="wrapper">
      <tr>
        <td class="videocontent">
          <div id="content1"></div>
          <div class="header">[text]</div>
          <div class="footer">[footer]</div>
        </td>

        <td class="videocontent">
          <div id="content2"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="videocontent">
          <div id="content3"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="videocontent">
          <div id="content4"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```